# Alert based on metric value compared to one of its own label values

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am using `kube-prometheus-stack` and the yaml snippets you see below are part of a `PrometheusRule` definition.

This is a completely hypothetical scenario, the simplest one I could think of that illustrates my point.

Given this kind of metric:

```
cpu_usage{job="job-1", must_be_lower_than="50"} 33.72
cpu_usage{job="job-2", must_be_lower_than="80"} 56.89
# imagine there are plenty more lines here
# with various different values for the must_be_lower_than label
# ...
```

I'd like to have alerts that check the label `must_be_lower_than` and alert. Something like this (this doesn't work the way it's written now, just trying to demonstrate):

```
alert: CpuUsageTooHigh
annotations:
  message: 'On job {{ $labels.job }}, the cpu usage has been above {{ $labels.must_be_lower_than }}% for 5 minutes.'
expr: cpu_usage > $must_be_lower_than
for: 5m
```

**P.S** I already know I can define alerts like this:

```yaml
alert: CpuUsageTooHigh50
annotations:
  message: 'On job {{ $labels.job }}, the cpu usage has been above 50% for 5 minutes.'
expr: cpu_usage{must_be_lower_than="50"} > 50
for: 5m
---
alert: CpuUsageTooHigh80
annotations:
  message: 'On job {{ $labels.job }}, the cpu usage has been above 80% for 5 minutes.'
expr: cpu_usage{must_be_lower_than="80"} > 80
for: 5m
```

This is not what I'm looking for, because I have to manually define alerts for *some* of the various values of the `must_be_lower_than` label.

Comment: AFAIK, landscape did not change, and Prometheus' philosophy is still against mixing up labels and values.

Answer (score 2):

See @markalex comment to this post, the `absent()` function can be used for generating metric with tags:

```
cpu_usage > ON(must_be_lower_than) GROUP_LEFT (absent(non_existent{must_be_lower_than="80"}) * 80 or absent(non_existent{must_be_lower_than="50"}) * 50)
```

---

***old answer***

There is currently no way in Prometheus to have this kind of "templating".

The only way to get something near would be to use recording rules that that define the maximum value for the label:

```
rules:
- record: max_cpu_usage
  expr: vector(50)
  labels:
    must_be_lower_than:"50"
- record: max_cpu_usage
  expr: vector(80)
  labels:
    must_be_lower_than:"80"
# ... other possible values
```

Then use it in your alerting rule:

```
alert: CpuUsageTooHigh
annotations:
  message: 'On job {{ $labels.job }}, the cpu usage has been above {{ $labels.must_be_lower_than}}% for 5 minutes.'
expr: cpu_usage > ON(must_be_lower_than) GROUP_LEFT max_cpu_usage
for: 5m
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I already assumed that what I was asking for was a bit too ambitious, but good to have confirmation. This method you're presenting is interesting, but has more or less the same problem in that I still have to manually define the values of the label that should be alerted on. My backup plan was to use helm templates to define the alerts (same style as what I mention in the P.S.), but I will also consider this. Thanks!

Comment: The only other way is to have somehow, something injecting the limits you want for your job. This is something you can do natively in node_exporter by using prom files.  It would be nice if, by example, kube-state-metrics was able to transform annotations into metrics,  we could use that to define limits.

Comment: I love ingenuity of this answer. To be fair though, it can be done without recording rules at a cost of loosing simpleness and elegance of expression: `cpu_usage > ON(must_be_lower_than) GROUP_LEFT (absent(non_existent{must_be_lower_than="80"}) * 80 or absent(non_existent{must_be_lower_than="50"}) * 50)`

Comment: @markalex good trick - that's much better than a recording rule

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is still (and I believe will always be) against mixing up labels and values. The only exception of this rule is method `count_values` that allows to convert value of metric into label, but that's it: no mechanisms to do the opposite are available.

Regarding your idea, I believe you trying to do it in a bit incorrect way. If you want to create alert for some of your metrics based on threshold specific to the machine this metrics are from, you should use additional metrics instead of additional labels.

I'm sorry I'm not that familiar with kube-stack, so I'll be using node exporter as an example, I believe this example should be easy to scale on another exporters.

So for your example, you should create a textfile metric

```
my_metric_threshold 80
```

configure node exporter to expose this textfile metric, and then use alert rule

```yaml
alert: CpuUsageTooHigh
annotations:
  message: 'On job {{ $labels.job }}, the cpu usage has been above {{ value }}% for 5 minutes.'
expr: my_metric_threshold > on(instance) my_metric
for: 5m
```

This way your thresholds are tied to your machine, and you don't need to reload Prometheus' config when you decided to add or change threshold.

Also, you can have more granularity with less hustle. To keep up with node exporter example you can use textfile metrics

```
cpu_must_be_lower_than{cpu="0"} 80
cpu_must_be_lower_than{cpu="1"} 50
```

and expression `cpu_must_be_lower_than > on(instance, cpu) (100 - 100 * rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}))`.

Comment: I like your answer! I'd like to engage with this a bit more, but I'll wait until I have more time to express my thoughts clearly. In the meantime, I'll award the bounty to you since it's close to expiring (and I'll probably forget about it if I don't do it now)

Comment: @igg, sure. Take any time to clarify everything for yourself, no rush. And thanks for the bounty)