# Prometheus variables on targets

Tags: prometheus

We want to use a nagios approach on prometheus if possible, usually you'll define a host like this:

```
      - targets:
          - 'test-02'
        labels:
          project: 'TEST'
          asset_name: 'test-02'
          asset_id: '4567'
          enviroment: 'N2'
          location: 'test'
          inheritance: 'child'
```

And this is the expr:

```
- alert: Memory critical
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 80
```

We want to make the "< 80" part a variable that is take from the host, we tried with this (and several more) but no lick so far:

```
#MEMORY

  - alert: Memory warning
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < float($mem_ram_crit
```

Anyone has any idea how? We've been checking on some websites (i.e. [Using variables in PrometheusRule expr field instead of contant values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019175/using-variables-in-prometheusrule-expr-field-instead-of-contant-values)) but that didnt work.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
I was recomended this: [Alert based on metric value compared to one of its own label values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949798/alert-based-on-metric-value-compared-to-one-of-its-own-label-values)
However, the exporters are not ours and changing how they behave may be a ton of work (we have a few hosts under this prom instance, and reinstalling all of them may take a while)

Comment: You can expose additional metric (using textfile collector) with expected level of usage, and create an alert based on that metric.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alert based on metric value compared to one of its own label values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949798/alert-based-on-metric-value-compared-to-one-of-its-own-label-values)

Comment: The problem is not to expose a new metric, the problem is that hosts that are the same type with the same kind of services may have for whatever reason different measurements on a "check" (ie, host1 has 80% memory ram consumed, and host2 which is balanced has 70%, so even though i want the same info from each host, i dont wanth them to share thesholds)

Comment: If you would expose new metric for threshold using textfile collector, you would get a separate threshold for each host, and thus you can set desired level as you want.

Comment: And adding a textfile exporter doesn't require re-instllation of a node_exporter, only adding one more collector (basically adding two parameters into start command for the service).

Comment: Alternatively, you can achieve similar result by adding recording rules, somewhat like in other answer. But instead of label `must_be_lower_than` you can use `instance` to link desired threshold to the host.

Comment: I dont know what are recording rules, however i am more thrilled about the textfile collector by putting there the desired thresholds aswell

Comment: Just so you know, the idea was to try smthng like 
          mem_ram_warn: '80'
          mem_ram_crit: '90'                                                                                        
        (in a nagios approach), but im starting to see that is not possible

Comment: I opened a request to see if it would be possible to use vars from files in expr, but i guess i'll have no luck on that one https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discussions/13800